# NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Methods not called on initial fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, delegates

Question thats been bugging me here:

Are NSFetchedResultsController "controllerDidChangeContent" etc delegate methods supposed to be called when initially fetching content or only when that initially fetched content is updated / changed?

Having an issue where even though the initial fetch comes back with the results, the delegate methods are not called unless that initial results batch changes (from a network request later on for example).

This means i currently need to force a collection view update with a reloadData() since waiting for the delegate methods to call fails when there is only existing content in core data and nothing new changing it.

I have confirmed that at the time the initial fetch completes, the delegate is set and the results are valid. Any gotchas i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate methods are only called for changes made after `performFetch:` has been called.  You can infer this from several statements in the class reference documentation.

Comment: Doh. I've read the documentation many many times and this still wasn't clear to me. Thanks.